# Reference Outlook's Public folder in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, macros

The VBA code below maps to the "test" folder in my inbox in Outlook.  I need it to map to the "TAT Monitor" folder which is a sub folder in the public folder in my Outlook(Public Folder>ABC Folder>123 Folder>Tat Monitor Folder).  I tried  plugging in "olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders" in place of "olFolderInbox" but it does not recognize it.

```
Public Sub GetAttachments()
Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
Dim Item As MailItem
Dim Atmt As Attachment
Dim FileName As String
Dim firstDate As Date
Dim secondDate As Date


Dim i As Integer


Set Inbox = GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders.Item("Test")
firstDate = Date - 1 + TimeValue("8:00:00am")
secondDate = Date - 1 + TimeValue("8:30:00am")

For Each Item In Inbox.Items
For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
If Item.SentOn > firstDate And Item.SentOn < secondDate Then

FileName = "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\TEST2\" & Atmt & ".xlsx"
Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
Else
End If
Next

Next

Set Inbox = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867877.aspx

```
Set Inbox = GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders).Folders.("ABC Folder").Folders.("123 Folder").Folders.("Tat Monitor Folder")
```

Typo when dropping the default "item"

```
Set Inbox = GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders).Folders("ABC Folder").Folders("123 Folder").Folders("Tat Monitor Folder")
```

Same as

```
Set Inbox = GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olPublicFoldersAllPublicFolders).Folders.Item("ABC Folder").Folders.Item("123 Folder").Folders.Item("Tat Monitor Folder")
```

Comment: Thanks  for the help!  However, I am getting a compile error at the "(" in "folders.("ABC Folder")".  Would you happen to know why?